# App crashes when going onto another activity that uses getSupportActionbar?

Tags: android-studio

I'm already using `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MainMenu");` for my main menu java file but when i want to use it for my second activity's java file it crashes the app. I've looked around for a solution but i cannot seem to find the correct one.

This is the code for the java file of my second activity (room service):

```
package com.example.prototype;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class RoomServiceMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_room_service_menu);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Room Service Menu");
    }
}
```

This is the error im getting:

```
2020-02-10 18:05:25.566 7046-7046/com.example.prototype E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.prototype, PID: 7046
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prototype/com.example.prototype.RoomServiceMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.prototype.RoomServiceMenu.onCreate(RoomServiceMenu.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Post your error stacktrace.

Comment: Ok i've posted it

Answer (score 0):

you work on a null object, after you want to set title on getSupportActionBar(), you should set a toolbar for this by using setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: How do i do that ?